# I want to prevent update of FirstName and LastName property which belongs to an object using Asp.net core fluent validations

Tags: c#, validation, fluent

This is my input DTO:

```
 public class IndividualInformation : IPerson
 {
     public string FirstName { get; set; }
     public string LastName { get; set; }
     public Address PrimaryAddress { get; set; }
     public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; set; }
     public string CitizenShip { get; set; }
 }
```

When a user tries to update the first and last name using fluent validation, I want to prevent it.

What rule would I need to write to do that?

Comment: Basically when entity is updated first time first and last name will have some value, after that no user should be able to update these two properties ,we want to do it using fluent validations provided by asp.net core.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are looking for immutable (readonly) properties. Here's an example:

```cs
 public class IndividualInformation : IPerson
 {
     public string FirstName { get; }
     public string LastName { get; }
     public Address PrimaryAddress { get; set; }
     public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; set; }
     public string CitizenShip { get; set; }

    public IndividualInformation(string firstName, string lastName)
    {
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
    }
 }

var info = new IndividualInformation("Jane", "Doe")
{
    PrimaryAddress = ...
};

info.FirstName = "John"; // this will throw an error
```

If you have C# 9 enabled, you can use `init` properties for this:

```cs
 public class IndividualInformation : IPerson
 {
     public string FirstName { get; init; }
     public string LastName { get; init; }
     public Address PrimaryAddress { get; set; }
     public DateTime? DateOfBirth { get; set; }
     public string CitizenShip { get; set; }
 }

var info = new IndividualInformation
{
    FirstName = "Jane",
    LastName = "Doe",
    PrimaryAddress = ...
};

info.FirstName = "John"; // this will throw an error
```